# Регулярное выражение для списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список, содержащий в себе множесто времён, например :

```
list = ['09:00', '10:00', '10:40', '11:00', '13:00']
```

Как найти все *элементы* списка, которые входят в диапазон между, например, тем, что введет пользователь?
Пример

```
x = input('Введите промежуток времени')
x = 10:00-11:00
```

То, что должно получиться на *выходе*

```
10:00
10:40
11:00
```

Comment: Примите тот ответ который вам больше помог(галочка у ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно изменять сам патерн поиска регулярного выражения и по нему парсить список времен:

```py
import re

zone = input().split('-')

mylist = ['09:00', '10:00', '10:40', '11:00', '13:00']

zone1_start, zone1_end = zone[0].split(':')[0], zone[0].split(':')[1]
zone2_start, zone2_end = zone[1].split(':')[0], zone[1].split(':')[1]

pattern = r'\d[{}-{}]:\d[{}-{}]'.format(zone1_start, zone2_start, zone1_end, zone2_end)

for item in mylist:
    print(re.match(pattern, item))
```

> 10:00-11:00

```
None
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='10:00'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='10:40'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='11:00'>
None
```

Comment: Очень трудное у вас решение(см мой ответ)

Answer (score 1):

```
timelist = ['09:00', '10:00', '10:40', '11:00', '13:00']
result = []
for i in timelist:
    if i.starswith("10") or i == "11:00":
        result.append(i)

print(*result)
```

Comment: ну во первых - мое решение соответствует вопросу(регулярное выражение), во вторых - а что если диапазон не час, а хотя бы два? от 10 до 12, тогда придется проверять не начинается ли с 10, 11 и не является ли двенадцатью, а если 10 часов?

Comment: @finally Вообще ваше решение лучше. Но мое проще, хотя подходит только для этой задачи, а если хоть что-нибудь поменять то ваше в выигрыше.

Comment: дело же не в лучше\хуже, просто ваше не охватывает весь спектр возможных входных значений, что не есть хорошо..